# monoDevelop crashes all the time

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm using monodevelop and monotouch to build iOS apps with C#. The IDE crashes many many times a day.

Has anyone else experienced the same problem? thanks

```
VERSION INFORMATION: -----------------------------------------------------

MonoDevelop 2.8.5
Runtime:
    Mono 2.10.8 (tarball Mon Dec 19 17:43:18 EST 2011)
    GTK 2.24.5
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)
Apple Developer Tools:
     Xcode 4.2 (828)
     Build 4C199
Monotouch: 5.0.4
Mono for Android not installed
Build information:
    Release ID: 20805000
    Git revision: c4deb930539ae87247b0bc43919dfcb98df215c2
    Build date: 2011-12-09 23:27:52+0000
Operating System:
    Mac OS X 10.6.8
```

crash log:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10580830/monodevelo%20crush%20log.rtf

Answer (score 0):

There have been a lot of fixes in the upcoming MonoDevelop 2.8.6, maybe that will solve this for you?

These sorts of issues are probably best reported on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: I just fixed another crash bug yesterday for 2.8.6.3 which happened when you try to Build your project when you have unsaved documents open. The problem was that the document saving had a side-effect of changing UI elements (like de-sensitizing the Save toolbar button, etc) from a non-UI thread, causing crashes in Gtk+.

Comment: Yeah thanks guys and sorry for posting this here, instead of bugzilla @ xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes.  I find I get the most crashes when debugging.  I am using MonoDevelop to write a MonoMac application, however currently I am mostly doing library and command line application development.  I seem to be running the same version as you.  Looking forward to an update.